# Update method in access table works just for the first call and in next calls just copy the first datas

Tags: c#, ms-access, datagridview

I have a access table in my form and 3 buttons for delete, update and insert.
Insert and delete works fine.
My problem is update. It works fine for the first run but when I select another row of datagridview it updates the row with last data (the first information that updated).

**Here is the updated code:**

```
    com.Connection = con;
                com.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                com.CommandText = "UPDATE login SET [password]=@password , [uname]=@uname , [ufamily]=@ufamily , [admin]=@admin WHERE username='" + textBox1.Text + "'";

                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", textBox2.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", textBox3.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ufamily", textBox4.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@admin", comboBox1.SelectedItem);
                con.Open();

                int result = com.ExecuteNonQuery();

                con.Close();

                if (result > 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("success");
                    SelectAllRecords();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("failed");
                }
```

This is my problem: I first updated row2 and it was ok. Later I updated row 4 and it just copied from row2 except the primary key (username (`textbox1`)).

and there is a method some kind of refresh table after update:

```
      public void SelectAllRecords()
            {
                com.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                com.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM login";
                com.Connection = con;
                con.Open();

                OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(com);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();

                adapter.Fill(ds, "login");
                dataGridView1.DataSource = null;


                dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["login"];
                dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "شناسه کاربری";
                dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = "کلمه عبور";
                dataGridView1.Columns[2].HeaderText = "نام";
                dataGridView1.Columns[3].HeaderText = "نام خانوادگی";
                dataGridView1.Columns[4].HeaderText = "سطح دسترسی";
                dataGridView1.Columns[5].HeaderText = "آخرین بازدید";
                dataGridView1.Columns[6].HeaderText = "آخرین مطلب";
                con.Close();

            }
and event of dataGridView1_CellEnter:

    private void dataGridView1_CellEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
            {
                if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                   this.textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                   this.textBox2.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                   this.textBox3.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                   this.textBox4.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                   if (dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[4].Value.ToString() == "مدیر")
                   {
                       this.comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       this.comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 1;
                   }
                   this.textBox6.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
                   this.textBox7.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[6].Value.ToString();
                   username = dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                }
            }
```

**edit:
more details:**
I select the row and enter values to textboxes and then click update button and it works fine and then I select another row and enter the values to textboxes but it updates the row with the last entered values.

Comment: In which event do you call the Update code?

Comment: in button click event

Comment: i guess problem is in datagaridview1_cellenter event but i cant find it

Comment: I think you could solve this with a debugger. Put a breakpoint in the update code and checks what values are present in the textboxes.

Comment: sorry im amature. how to put break point?

Comment: Select the line where you want to stop your code. Press F9, then run your app until it reaches the breakpoint line, look at variables values hovering over them with your mouse or open the local window, press F10 to advance line by line

Answer (score 0):

In your update query.please update your data using id. get the id from your grid-view.